# Creating ActiveRecord query to always show an exam not previously done by student (Rails app)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

On this feature I'm adding to my school's app, an User has a new Checkup (a short English test) being presented by the system for them to do every 4 weeks. I want to build a query that always retrieves from the database a Checkup that hasn't been previously answered by the student. Since the models are associated, I believe this is simple, but I do not know how to code the query using Rails (have done research and wasn't able to find an answer). There are three models to be considered here: User, Answer and Checkup. I have a separate Answer model for the answers the students give, because they have to be processed separately due to other features of the app. This is the User model:

```
 class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :answers
 end
```

This is the Answer model:

```
class Answer < ApplicationRecord

   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :checkup

end
```

And this is the Checkup model

```
class Checkup < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :answers
end
```

In the controller of the page where the Checkup is shown, I wish to have a variable in the page's action that holds the retrieved Checkup:

```
def exams
   @next_checkup = #the ActiveRecord query goes here 
end
```

The query needs to retrieve a Checkup that doesn't have in its related answers an answer given by the current user (the user of an answer can be retrieved by the attribute "user_id"). How should I code the query? Thanks!

Comment: Is there an association between checkups and users too? Or how do you know what checkups was already done by what users?

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me. There is is no association between Users and Checkups, and it was done on purpuse, since the checkups won't be always used as exams. However It is possible to know which users did a particular checkup through checkup.answers. Each answer has a user_id assigned to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try:

```
@next_checkup = Checkup.where.not(id: current_user.answers.pluck(:checkup_id)).first
```

Comment: Yep, it worked! Thank you Spicker!